# ¿Como sacar cantidad de días entre dos fechas en C#, Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Este es mi codigo con los calendarios:

Textbox 1:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Texbox 2:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Mi codigo Jquery para los calendarios:

```
  <script>
  $(function () {
      $("[id*=txtDate1]").datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/calendario.png",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "a",
          minDate: 0,
          maxDate: 2,
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
      });

  });



 </script>
     <script>
        $(function () {
          $("[id*=txtDate2]").datepicker({
             showOn: "button",
             buttonImage: "images/calendario.png",
             buttonImageOnly: true,
             buttonText: "a",
             minDate: 2,
             dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
         });

     });
```

Esto es lo único que he hecho de lado de C#:

```
  DateTime fechaUno = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate1.Text);
  DateTime fechaDos = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text);

   TimeSpan difFechas = fechaDos.Subtract(fechaUno);
```

Comment: Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, la pregunta que tengo para ti es ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo desde lado del server o desde el cliente, para eso puedes hacer algo como en esta [repuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950731/get-the-number-of-days-between-2-dates-using-datepicker)

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco Como esto:                                                  
                                                                                                   
    DateTime fechaUno = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate1.Text);
            DateTime fechaDos = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text);

            TimeSpan difFechas = fechaDos - fechaUno;

Comment: Puedes usar `TimeSpan difFechas = fechaDos.Subtract(fechaUno);`

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ¿Como guardo el resultado en una variable?,al parecer hay que convertirlo a string.Bueno,imprimir el resultado en un label.

Comment: @luis  agrega el código a tu pregunta para ver que has intentado hacer.

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco la verdad no he hecho mucho,pero ahí va...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien,ya pude dar con la solución:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Codigo JQuery:

```
  <script>
      $(function () {
      $("[id*=txtDate1]").datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendario.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "a",
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: 2,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
    });

  });
  </script>


     <script>
    $(function () {
      $("[id*=txtDate2]").datepicker({
         showOn: "button",
         buttonImage: "images/calendario.png",
         buttonImageOnly: true,
         buttonText: "a",
         minDate: 2,
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
     });

    });
</script>
```

Codigo C#:

```
        DateTime fechaUno = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate1.Text).Date;
        DateTime fechaDos = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text).Date;

        TimeSpan difFechas = fechaDos - fechaUno;

        int days = (int)difFechas.TotalDays;

        string dias = Convert.ToString(days);

        lbl1.Text = dias;
```

Comment: Te sugiero marcar esta respuesta como solución aceptada, es una buena práctica de stackoverflow